# MySQL Get All Children in a Column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
----------------------
| ID | Name | Parent |
----------------------
| 1  |  a   | null   |
| 2  |  b   | null   |
| 3  |  c   | 1      |
| 4  |  d   | 3      |
| 5  |  e   | 2      |
| 6  |  f   | 2      |
----------------------
```

with an unknown number of possible depth to the parent/child relationship.

I want a query that will give me the following result:

```
-----------------
| ID | Children |
-----------------
| 1  | 3,4      | -- because 4 is a child of 3, and 3 is a child of 1, it should show in both
| 2  | 5,6      |
| 3  | 4        |
| 4  | null     |
| 5  | null     |
| 6  | null     |
-----------------
```

Is it possible to get this kind of result in a query? I've been trying everything I know to try, and searching everywhere and have not found something that will give me this result.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySQL Version 5.7

Comment: @forpas that's part of my problem. I found a solution that works in MySQL 8.0, but I'm using MariaDB which is currently based on 5.7

Comment: @Randy you can use `FIND_IN_SET` for this purpose

Comment: @aRvi Care to elaborate? I'm not sure how that particular function would help me in this case.

Comment: finally i got it. Let me share you my solution

Comment: This structure is a fairly obvious way of storing a tree structure in a relational database - but as you have found it is rather limiting in the ways you can interact with the data - there are lots more models - https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/3dc517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering out table as `employees` with fields `ID, Name, Parent`.

***Approach 1: When we know the depth of our hierarchy***
We can simply join our table `n` time equal to our hierarchy and can use `GROUP BY` to get the desired results. Here it is 3 so

```
SELECT t1.ID AS lev1,  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', t2.ID, t3.ID)) AS childs
FROM employees AS t1
LEFT JOIN employees AS t2 ON t2.Parent = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN employees AS t3 ON t3.Parent = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Corresponding fiddle you can look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62cf6a/1/0).

***Approach 2: When we don't know the depth of our hierarchy***

We'll create two procedures for that.

1. `store_emp_childs` - It will store parent and its child in a temporary table.
2. `get_emp_child` - It will create temp table, call `store_emp_childs` to generate resultset. Select(return) the data from temporary table and remove the temporaray table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_emp_child`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE `tmp_emp_child` (
        `emp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `child_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`, `child_id`)
    );
    
    CALL store_emp_childs(NULL, '');
    
    SELECT e.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(ec.child_id) AS childs
    FROM employees e
    LEFT JOIN tmp_emp_child ec ON e.ID = ec.emp_id
    GROUP BY e.ID;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_emp_child;
END
```

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `store_emp_childs`(
    IN `int_parent` INT,
    IN `old_parents` VARCHAR(100)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished, current_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DEClARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM employees WHERE IFNULL(Parent, 0) = IFNULL(int_parent, 0);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cur;

    curID: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO current_id;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE curID;
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO tmp_emp_child (emp_id, child_id)
        SELECT id, current_id FROM employees WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, old_parents) OR id = int_parent
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE emp_id = emp_id;
        
        CALL store_emp_childs(current_id, CONCAT(old_parents, ',', current_id));
    END LOOP curID;
    CLOSE cur;
END
```

Note:

1. We are recursively calling our `store_emp_childs`. It requires `max_sp_recursion_depth` parameter to be set more than 0. I recommend to make it 250. It will not work if records are more than this recursion depth. Will look further to improve this.
2. We are creating temporary table, so user should have rights to create that.

Comment: A very nice article, if you want to see a new way to store such info and retrieve them. [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySql](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked with 1 small change... I just had to change the delimiter, then put the new delimiter after each `END` statement, then change the delimiter back.